# Swift, NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(): update data in operation during operation is running?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsoperationqueue

I use background file downloading in IOS project, and when file downloading is started, progress view's update is started by block `NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock()` in method:

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
    if totalBytesExpectedToWrite == NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown {
       println("Unknown transfer size");
    }
     else{
       let data = getDBInfoWithTaskIdentifier(downloadTask.taskIdentifier)

       NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock(){
           data.db_info.downloadProgress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
            let inf = data.db_info.indexPath
            let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: data.index, inSection: 0)) as SettingsTableViewCell
            cell.downloadProgress.hidden = false
            cell.downloadProgress.setProgress(data.db_info.downloadProgress, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

When view with download UI is dismissed and present once more, `self.tableView` is new object, but `self.tableView` in `NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()` operation, which update progress view, is old one, that what was before dismissing. Println() returns two different objects. Is there possibility update data about `self.tableView` in that `NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()` block?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should consider switch to GCD (Grand Central Dispatch).

Your problem arises because the reference to the `tableView` is captured in the closure. You can consider to put the logic in a separate class function so  `tableView` is not exposed in your closure. It has an added benefit of cleaner, more organised code.

Here is a general idea:

```
// new function
func setProgressInCell (data:?) { // '?' because i do not know the type
    let inf = data.db_info.indexPath
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: data.index, inSection: 0)) as SettingsTableViewCell
    cell.downloadProgress.hidden = false
    cell.downloadProgress.setProgress(data.db_info.downloadProgress, animated: true)

}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
    if totalBytesExpectedToWrite == NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown {
       println("Unknown transfer size");
    }
     else{
       let data = getDBInfoWithTaskIdentifier(downloadTask.taskIdentifier)

       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())  {
           [weak self] in
           data.db_info.downloadProgress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
           self.setProgressInCell(data)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found out why it has old `self.tableView`, it is because of background session still has dismissed view as delegate, not new one, and I have no idea, is it possible to update NSURLSession delegate or not. Even using your code, URLSession deals with dismissed view and doesn't have connection with newly presented.